# CtrlP should never index particular directories

Tags: plugin-ctrlp, working-directory

My projects are in:

```
/home/user/projectA
/home/user/projectB
```

However, at times I hit CtrlP and I haven't opened a file in a particular project, so my working directory is `/home/user`. CtrlP starts indexing this whole directory, which is huge and takes a whole lot of time every time I accidentally hit CtrlP. How can I avoid this? I have seen that I can exclude files and directories using Vim's wildignore and CtrlP's own g:ctrlp_custom_ignore, but that doesn't work as I can't ignore a parent directory and still search in a child directory. Any ideas?

Alternatively, I would also be happy with Vim automatically making `/home/user/projectA` the default working directory, just to avoid ever having `/home/user` as the working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways of doing that:

- On your terminal, move to your project directory then execute vim.
- Manually specify the working directory into vim using `:cd` command (You can check the current working directory with `:pwd`).

### Extra

#### CtrlP

If you're using [`ag` with ctrlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285751/use-ag-in-ctrlp-vim), you can create a `.agignore` file into your working directory, and specify there what ctrlp should ignore and not index.

#### A little but useful vim command

In my vimrc I have the following command:

```
command! Dir :cd %:p:h
```

So with `Dir` I can set the current vim working directory to the current file's path, its useful sometimes.

---

**EDIT:**

You can use vim autocommands (`h autocmd`) to automate the process.

Example if you want to make `/path/project` be your cwd in each vim start, add then to your vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :cd /path/project
```

The event `VimEnter` is quite understandable (`h autocmd-events`).

Comment: Thanks but it seems that this won't solve my issues. Is there a way of forcing my initial working directory (upon starting vim) to be a particular directory? Independently from how I start it. Your tips are useful but my goal is not having to go to a particular directory in the terminal or change the working directory manually... the idea is that this is done by default. And although I _am_ using ag with ctrlp, the problem is if I exclude the parent directory, the child directories won't be indexed either...

Comment: You can use vim autocommands for that (I've edited my post).